# Blue Prism Write to Web Client

Tags: blueprism

Has anyone had any problems writing data to a web client data field?
Having spied the field to be written in, the write action correctly writes the value from the data item into the web field. We then "Save" the value in the field by clicking the Save button.  This is when the value reverts back to the value that was previously in the field and does not save the new value. 
Copying the value from the data item and pasting it directly into the web field and hitting save works fine, but for some reason when Blue Prism does the write action and then save, the new value is not saved.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to the way the web application is coded - specifically, the data in the box is not acknowledged until a keydown event (or similar) is fired. When you copy/paste the data into the field, it fires a similar event where it believes the user to have interacted with the field.

The solution for this type of field is to use the Send Keys or Global Send Keys functionalities of Blue Prism to send the desired text.

Comment: Hi esqew,
Intriguing, would I need to re- spy the field?  Sorry how would I enable the global send key?

Answer (score 1):

It happens when the target application uses java script events to sense the changes in the element. To handle this , you have to use the send keys in following format. 
1. Focus the application / Control
2. Send Global mouse click centre to the element
3. Send "Sendkeys" to the application now.
4. Focus a dummy element in the page to let the page sense your input.

Answer (score 0):

If the old value is already higlighted when the spied field is selected, try getting BP to delete it first, then paste in the new value, then click on the field again, then save. If this doesn't work, then uncheck the URL attribute of the application model you are using for the spied field and try this again.